# How does Objective-C do reference counting efficiently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, garbage-collection, automatic-ref-counting, reference-counting

I'm taking a college course about compilers and we just finished talking about garbage collection and ways to free memory.  However, in class lectures and in our textbook, I was led to believe that reference counting was not a great way to manage memory.

The reasoning was that that reference counting is very expensive because the program has to insert numerous additional instructions to increment and decrement the reference count.  Additionally, everytime the reference count changes, the program has to check if it equals zero and if so, reclaim the memory.

My textbook even has the sentence:  "On the whole, the problems with reference counting outweight its advantages and it is rarely used for automatic storage management in programming language environments.

My questions are: Are these legitamate concerns?  Does objective-c avoid them somehow? If so how?

Comment: "numerous additional instructions" - numeruos == one; `INC [esp + 12]`. Also, Objective-C uses hand-tuned assembly and is also a compiled language => fast.

Comment: need a LOCK prefix on that INC, and it doesn't take into account objc's side table, and Instruments support

Comment: I would disagree, reference counting is a very effective way to manage  the complexities of manual memory management. It is not for all situations, but performance and control far out perform any garbage collection.

Comment: @Catfish_Man Technically, of course, but the point is that it's not that expensive as it might be taught to students.

Comment: C++ also does the same thing with shared_ptr

Comment: that text book must be written by a java extremist.

Comment: Eh. They're not wrong. A good GC can get great throughput, and garbage collected languages are very widespread. It's just not the whole picture.

Comment: ARC works in large part because the Objectve-C Analyzer works very well.  By intensively analyzing the code (and placing certain restrictions on how/when pointers are copied) it's possible to get the actual runtime management code/overhead down to a dull roar.

Comment: @JustinMeiners, that's wrong. Tracing GC has better CPU throughput than RC. See my answer below (will post in a second).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reference counting does have meaningful overhead, it's true. However, the "classic textbook" solution of tracing garbage collectors are not without downsides as well. The biggest one is nondeterminism, but pausing vs throughput is a significant concern as well.

In the end though, ObjC doesn't really get a choice. A state of the art copying collector requires certain properties of the language (no raw pointers for example) that ObjC just doesn't have. As a result, trying to apply the textbook solution to ObjC ends up requiring a partially conservative, non-copying collector, which in practice is around the same speed as refcounting but without its deterministic behavior.

(edit) My personal feelings are that throughput is a secondary, or even tertiary, concern and that the really important debate comes down to deterministic behavior vs cycle collection and heap compaction by copying. All three of those are such valuable properties that I'd be hard-pressed to pick one.

Comment: But the significant, "meaningful overhead" price is paid on the fly, as deallocation occurs (as opposed to the trivial cost of decrementing the ref-count) hence even if your code deallocates a whole object graph as the result of a single ref-count decrement, not only is this a consequence of how your code is written (your code decided to decrement that ref-count), but it also spreads such cost throughout the whole life-time of your app, without any user noticeable pauses. There must be reasons Apple is phasing out even their state of the art Generational Garbage Collector for ObjC on OS X ...

Comment: libauto (Apple's GC) is the partially conservative, non-copying collector that I mentioned. It has issues with false roots, heap fragmentation, and so-so performance (though much better than typical C garbage collectors).

Comment: You can, of course, have (Java-style) GC without copying and pauses.

Comment: Sure. It's just slower and fragments the heap.

Comment: Actually, properly done it's as fast, if not faster than the "traditional" Java GC, and does not suffer serious heap fragmentation.  The IBM iSeries "classic" JVM was "on top of the heap" for several years, in large part because of the non-copying, non-pausing GC.  (Eventually it fell behind because IBM didn't want to invest in that technology any more.)

Comment: Interesting. Got anything I could read on that? The locality of reference/fragmentation advantages of copying are pretty dramatic from what I've read, so I'd love to see research on other approaches :)

Comment: I've got some articles at home, but I'd have to dig them out.  Basically, the trick is to break heap into segments, with each segment treated as an array of fixed-size heap allocations.  Storage is kept quite compact and there are enormous efficiencies in the way you process the segments during a (concurrent) GC cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The consensus on RC vs. tracing in computer science research has been, for a long time, that tracing has superior CPU throughput despite longer (maximum) pause times. (E.g. see [here](ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/garbage/gcsurvey.ps), [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mckinley/papers/urc-oopsla-2003.pdf), and [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~steveb/downloads/pdf/rcix-oopsla-2013.pdf).) Only very recently, in 2013, has there been a paper (last link under those three) presenting an RC based system that performs equally or a little better than the best tested tracing GC, with regard to CPU throughput. Needless to say it has no "real" implementations yet.

Here is a tiny benchmark I just did on my iMac with 3.1 GHz i5, in the iOS 7.1 64-bit simulator:

```
long tenmillion = 10000000;
NSTimeInterval t;

t = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:tenmillion];
for (long i = 0; i < tenmillion; ++i)
    [arr addObject:[NSObject new]];
NSLog(@"%f seconds: Allocating ten million objects and putting them in an array.", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - t);

t = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
for (NSObject *obj in arr)
    [self doNothingWith:obj]; // Can't be optimized out because it's a method call.
NSLog(@"%f seconds: Calling a method on an object ten million times.", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - t);

t = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSObject *o;
for (NSObject *obj in arr)
    o = obj;
NSLog(@"%f seconds: Setting a pointer ten million times.", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - t);
```

With ARC disabled (`-fno-objc-arc`), this gives the following:

```
2.029345 seconds: Allocating ten million objects and putting them in an array.
0.047976 seconds: Calling a method on an object ten million times.
0.006162 seconds: Setting a pointer ten million times.
```

With ARC enabled, that becomes:

```
1.794860 seconds: Allocating ten million objects and putting them in an array.
0.067440 seconds: Calling a method on an object ten million times.
0.788266 seconds: Setting a pointer ten million times.
```

Apparently allocating objects and calling methods became somewhat cheaper. Assigning to an object pointer became more expensive by orders of magnitude, **though don't forget that I didn't call -retain in the non-ARC example**, and note that you can use `__unsafe_unretained` should you ever have a hotspot that assigns object pointers like crazy. Nevertheless, if you want to "forget about" memory management and let ARC insert retain/release calls where ever it wants, you will, in the general case, be wasting lots of CPU cycles, repeatedly and in all code pathes that set pointers. A tracing GC on the other hand leaves your code itself alone, and only kicks in at select moments (usually when allocating something), doing its thing in one fell swoop. (Of course the details are a **lot** more complicated in truth, given generational GC, incremental GC, concurrent GC, etc.)

So yes, since Objective-C's RC uses atomic retain/release, it is rather expensive, but Objective-C also has many more inefficiencies than that imposed by refcounting. (For instance, the fully dynamic/reflective nature of methods, which can be "swizzled" at any time by at run-time, prevents the compiler from doing many cross-method optimizations that would require data flow analysis and such. An objc_msgSend() is always a call to a "dynamically linked" black box from the view of the static analyzer, so to say.) All in all Objective-C as a language is not exactly the most efficient or best optimizable out there; people call it "C's type safety with Smalltalk's blazing speed" for a reason. ;-)

When writing Objective-C, one generally just instruments around well-implemented Apple libraries, which surely use C and C++ and assembly or whatever for their hotspots. Your own code barely ever needs to be efficient. When there is a hot spot, you can make it very efficient by dropping down to lower level constructs like pure C-style code within a single Objective-C method, but one rarely ever needs this. That's why Objective-C can afford the cost of ARC in the general case. I'm not yet convinced that tracing GC has any **inherent** problems in memory-constrained environments and think one could use a properly high-level language to instrument said libraries just as well, but apparently RC sits better with Apple/iOS. One has to consider the whole of the framework they've built up so far and all their legacy libraries when asking oneself why they didn't go with a tracing GC; for instance I've heard that RC is rather deeply built into CoreFoundation.

Answer (score 0):

> On the whole, the problems with reference counting outweight its advantages and it is rarely used for automatic storage management in programming language environments

The tricky word is `automatic`

Manual reference counting which is the traditional Obj-C way to do things, avoids the problems by delegating them to the programmer. The programmer has to know about the reference counting and manually add `retain` and `release` calls. If he/she creates a reference cycle, he/she is responsible for solving it.

The modern automatic reference counting does a lot of things for the programmer but still it's not a transparent storage management. The programmer still has to know about reference counting, still has to solve the reference cycles.

What's really tricky is to create a framework which handles memory managment by reference counting transparently, that is, without the need for the programmer to know about it. That's why it isn't used for automatic storage management.

The performance loss caused by additional instructions is not very big and usually it's not important.

Comment: Yep, Objective-C "automatic" reference counting is basically just manual reference counting with the human element replaced by the Analyzer (and with a lot of restrictions placed on the programmer to make that possible).  Think about it -- 95% (at least) of "manual" reference counting in Objective-C is "automatic" -- you always make pointer properties retain, and you always release them in `dealloc`.  Etc.  While the new ARC support is impressive in its sophistication, it's not that hard of a problem conceptually.